# WARNING: Got result of null when trying to get Boolean. in fieldexpression validation in struts 2

Tags: java, validation, struts2

I have action class and do validation in xml. All validation is successful except this one

```
<validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="fieldname">personBean.carModels</param>
        <param name="expression"><![CDATA[personBean.carModels.length>0]]></param>
        <message>You must select at least one value</message>
    </validator>
```

The warning is:

```
лют. 01, 2014 8:03:53 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger warn
WARNING: Got result of null when trying to get Boolean.
```

In personBean class there is List `carModels` with getters and setters.
If I do not use validation with the above code then all is ok and `carModels` is updated.

Why is this?

Thank you!

Comment: It is not null. I printed the content of `carModels` and it is ok. But validation fails anyway.

Comment: Thanks for tip but it didn't help.

Comment: `List` doesn't have a method `length`, have you tried `personBean.carModels.size`?